# Negative vs Positive Free Logic Witness

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Free logic comes in different flavors(*). In negative free
logic a predicate with non-existent argument is supposed
to fail. In positive free logic there is no such restriction

which leads to a dual universe semantics. What would be a
closed free logic formula, that is a theorem of negative free logic, but
not a theorem of positive free logic.

(*)
**Free Logic - Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy**
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/

Comment: IMO it is the other way... There are formulas, like $t=t$ that are valid in positive semantics but not valid in the negative one. See examples in SEP's entry.

Comment: A sentence related to this, theorem in negative free logic, but not theorem in positive free logic, would be Πx(~E!x=>~x=x). But it uses Meinongian quantifer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, gotcha, a solution, is relatively simple. Take this FOL formula:

```
   FOL |- ~∃xp(x) => ~p(a)
```

It is provable in FOL. It is not provable in positive free logic.
At least this translation is not provable in FOL:

```
   /* shows ~∃xp(x) => ~p(a) is not provable
      in positive free logic */
   FOL |/- ~∃x(u(x) & p(x)) => ~p(a)
```

But it is provable in negative free logic.
At least this translation is provable in FOL:

```
   /* shows ~∃xp(x) => ~p(a) is provable
      in negative free logic */
   FOL |- ∀x(p(x) => u(x)) => (~∃x(u(x) & p(x)) => ~p(a))
```